# Why this Duplicate doesn't work?

Tags: administration, sales, duplicate-matching-rule

I've this duplicate rule on Account cause I want to prevent update and create Accounts with same Record Type and "User ID" (a custom field on the Vendor Account Record Type)

But if I try to update a duplicate record it doesn't work.
The rule is active.

[image]

Here's the Matching Rule.

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification, you made sure that you activated the Matching Rule as well? Can we see what that looks like?

Comment: The Matching Rule is Active, it works on create but not on edit.